# c# windowsform , What is next step before deployment?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-injection

Just finished my Winforms program for Clinics with database in sql managment Studio. 
My Connection is ADO.NET Entity Data Model I mean edmx. I want to ask you guys what is next step and asking you if you see any injection problem
and how should I protect from Injection. All my code is Linq and I belive with Linq you get less problem of Injections. 
My questions are three questions:

1) What kind of changes must I do in settings in my Visual project before deploying alaive on real server.
Is there any changes to do in Properity of my winforms Project? Becouse now this will be Production project.

2) My second question is, Do you see guys any lack of Security in my code when I add a new person, or when I search a person? And How should I do for the security sake?
See my some of my code below please

3) Is (ADO.NET Entity Data Model, ADO.NET Entity Data Model)  normal to use for such kind of big system? 
becouse my connectionstring is in App.config and it's very long string like this below and its geting me litle scared.. ;)

```
<add name="ClinicEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyHealthModel.csdl|res://*/MyHealthModel.ssdl|res://*/MyHealthModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyComputerName;initial catalog=ClinicDb;user id=***;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Here is some of my code:
When searching person:

```
private void SearchPatient()
{
try
            {
                using (ClinicEntities db = new ClinicEntities())
                {
                    if(txtIdCardnr.Text != string.Empty)
                    {
                        string IdCard = txtIdCardnr.Text.Trim();
                        var patId = db.Patient.Where(x => x.IdentityCardNr == IdCard).FirstOrDefault();
                        if(patId != null)
                        {
                            var reservation = (from u in db.Registration
                                            join p in db.Patient on u.PatientId equals p.PatientId
                                            join ....... you got the idea 
                                            where ......  
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                ReservationNr = u.ReservNr,
                                                ReservationDate = u.ReservationDate,
                                                ........
                                            }

                                  ).ToList();

                            dgvReservations.DataSource =  reservation;

                        }


                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Exception inner = ex.InnerException;
                while (inner != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(inner.Message);
                    inner = inner.InnerException;
                }
            }
}
```

And for adding new reservation:

```
private async void AddReservation()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ClinicEntities db = new ClinicEntities())
                {
                    if (IsValidated())
                    { 
                        Reservation pat = new Reservation();
                        pat.SymptomId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbSymptom.SelectedValue);
                        pat.SymptonDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
                        pat.SymptonTime = txtTime.Text.Trim();
                        pat.Notes = txtNoteEmg.Text.Trim();
                        pat.RegisterdBy = StaffId;
                        pat.PatientId = PatientId;  
                        db.Reservation.Add(pat);
                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();


                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Exception inner = ex.InnerException;
                while (inner != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(inner.Message);
                    inner = inner.InnerException;
                }
            }
        }
```

So, du you see guys any lack of security in my code? Thank you again for helping me to get all three questions.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow is not the place for code review (but there is a stack exchange site for code review and your question may be on topic there)

1) I'm not really sure how the server comes into this equation; surely it's only offering this winforms app for download, like any other file. No changes should be needed

2) I see an unencrypted plain text password in your config file, but whether you care or not is another matter. It could be that even if the user did open the local db with the password they found and have a look around they can't do any real damage. Now if that password is the same as your production server it might be more of an issue... The LINQ you have written to do your db access is immune to SQL injection. The only way to make it liable is to execute raw sql command that have had user provided values concatenated into them

3) I'm not sure StackOverflow is the place to seek help with a phobia of long connection strings. It works; leave it alone (other than encrypting the password maybe)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will post it on recomended site. Thank you again

Comment: That wasn't an instruction to post it on code review, it was an advice that codereview exists and you should check carefully whether your Question is on topic for their site